# symfony2 : how to clear cache automatically in dev?

Tags: php, caching, symfony

This problem has occured all of a sudden so I guess I must have done something wrong with my Symfony2 project...

Whenever I run the application in dev (I use netbeans as an IDE, don't know if it matters), if I make a modification to the code (PHP, HTML or Javascript), I will not see any change until I delete all the content of the `/app/cache/dev` folder !

This is obviously slowing me down a lot. How do I fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

in app_dev.php I had not set debug mode to true. newbie mistake I guess.

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... if you have enabled an Opcache (accel) in your php.ini this could be the reason. It was the reason in my case anyway. I don't get what exactly causes this issue, but I worked out my own dirty fix. I have added a call to the opcache_reset() function on the very top of my app_dev.php file (which is located in your Symfony2 project in "web" folder).

---

```
opcache_reset();
```

---

Works for me. Hope it will work for you too.